# FileInputStream in Another class?

Tags: java, android, file, syntax

I'm loading a file that has been saved by another class via the FileOutputstream method. Anyway, I want to load that file in another class, but it either gives me syntax errors or crashes my App.

The only tutorials I could find where they saved and loaded the file in the same class, but I want to load it up in another class and couldn't find how to solve the problem of loading into another class.

Thanks

My Code:

```
public class LogIn extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText eTuser;
EditText eTpassword;
CheckBox StaySignedIn;
Button bSubmit;
String user;
String pass;
FileOutputStream fos;
FileInputStream fis = null;
String FILENAME = "userandpass";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    eTuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTuser);
    eTpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eTpassword);
    StaySignedIn = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Cbstay);
    bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogIn);
    bSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);
    if (file.exists()) {
        Intent i = new Intent(LogIn.this, ChatService.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    // if if file exist close bracket
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // end of catch bracket
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // end of catch

} // create ends here

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.bLogIn:
        String user = eTuser.getText().toString();
        String pass = eTpassword.getText().toString();
        Bundle userandpass = new Bundle();
        userandpass.putString("user", user);
        userandpass.putString("pass", pass);
        Intent login = new Intent(LogIn.this, logincheck.class);
        login.putExtra("pass", user);
        login.putExtra("user", pass);
        startActivity(login);

        if (StaySignedIn.isChecked())
            ;
        String userstaysignedin = eTuser.getText().toString();
        String passstaysignedin = eTpassword.getText().toString();
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            fos.write(userstaysignedin.getBytes());
            fos.write(passstaysignedin.getBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // end of try bracket, before the Catch IOExceptions e.
            e.printStackTrace();

        } // end of catch bracket

    } // switch and case ends here
}// Click ends here

}// main class ends here
```

Class B( Class that loads the data.)

```
public class ChatService extends Activity {
String collected = null;
FileInputStream fis = null;
String FILENAME;
TextView userandpass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chatservice);
    userandpass = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try {
        fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    byte[] dataArray = null;
    try {
        dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1)
            ;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    {
        // while statement
    }
    userandpass.setText(collected);

}// create ends here
```

}// class ends here

LogCat:

```
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gta5news.bananaphone/com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ContextImpl.makeFilename(ContextImpl.java:1599)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openFileInput(ContextImpl.java:399)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openFileInput(ContextWrapper.java:152)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at com.gta5news.bananaphone.ChatService.onCreate(ChatService.java:25)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-03 21:03:34.725: E/AndroidRuntime(279):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load FileInputStream in a septate class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548318/how-to-load-fileinputstream-in-a-septate-class)

Comment: No, it's not, I changed some of my code to get it to work, but it crashes.

Comment: *it crashes* is the poorest description of the problem you could give. Java has stack traces, which indicate the nature and location of the problem. Read it.

Comment: I updated the thread, I don't know what you expect me to write, I outlined the problem, there's not much else I can write? Do you want an essay from my design brief?

Comment: @user1245593 This is easy where have you defined your `String FILENAME;` ? in the first place in your second activity that's most likely why you get your NPE and you probably have to do the same stuff in the second activity `File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(FILENAME);` and provide the correct `FILENAME`

Comment: @user1245593 if you don't give us a detailed description of the problem, then we can't help you solve it. People are asking for details so they can help you - there's no need to be snarky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FILENAME` string in the `ChatService` class is null. So you get a `NullPointerException` when you try to load a file using `fis = openFileInput(FILENAME)`.

Also, your read loop throws away the data:

```
    while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1)
        ;
```

It needs to collect the data and set the value of your `collected` String.

Comment: Set FILENAME to be a valid filename string, e.g. `String FILENAME = "userandpass";` like you have in the other class. Otherwise how can your code know what file to load?

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace tells you everything you need to know.

The error is a NullPointerException (meaning that you pass a null reference to a method expecting a non null reference, or that you call a method on a null reference).

The error occurs inside some android code (`ContextWrapper.openFileInput()`), which is called by your `ChatService.onCreate()` method, on line 25.

The line 25 is the following line:

```
fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
```

So the error is clear: `FILENAME` is null. You haven't initialized it before this method is called.

Comment: I put my filename string to null and it still crashes.

Comment: Of course. Being null is the problem. So set it to the correct value - the name of the file you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your program flow and if your two classes are running in the same thread, but it looks like you have a program flow issue.  You are trying to open the file and getting a NullPointerException.  Make sure the file is created and you have the correct reference to it before attempting to read.

If they are running in separate threads then you might try something like this:

```
try {
    int waitTries=1;
    fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
    while(fis.available()<EXPECTEDSIZE && waitTries++<10)
        Tread.sleep(50);
}
```

If you know how large the file should be (EXPECTEDSIZE is some constant you will set), then this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: No, in ChatService, because that is where you are reading the file.  The point of the while loop is that it forces the program to wait until the whole file has been created before reading it. Another alternative is to have a boolean flag set by your loginClass after it closes the file: doneWriting=true, then my while loop above could just become while(!Login.doneWriting)